# How can I combine ranges of data while transposing them using a formula, in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Currently, the sheet looks like this:
[image]

and we need it to look like this:
[image]

How can I achieve that using a formula? I have tried with separate formulas in each row, but it does not look right - feasible.
Here is the [sample for tests](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit#gid=994734517), if you feel like giving it a shot.

Comment: this is a very common problem called "unpivoting".  That term might help improve your ability to search for the right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a very common problem called "unpivoting".

In Google sheets formulas, this is one of the ways to do it:

You will find the following formula in cell A28 on the tab called mk_Help:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT({FLATTEN(A3:A24&"|"&E1:G1&" "&E2:G2&"|"&E2:G2&"|"&B3:B24&"|"&C3:C24&"|"&E3:G24);FLATTEN(H3:H24&"|"&L1:N1&" "&L2:N2&"|"&L2:N2&"|"&I3:I24&"|"&J3:J24&"|"&L3:N24)};"|";0;0);"where Col1<>'' and Col6 is not null";0))
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks!

Comment: welcome.  You don't actually need both the month and the year in separate columns (as you can see from an additional solution)